# How create selectOneMenu with List<Objects> in JSF?

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I tried create `<h:selectOneMenu` with custom objects.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{OperatorsReportBean.languagesList}" style="width:100%"
                                     converter="#{langListConverter}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{OperatorsReportBean.languages}" var="langList"
                                       itemLabel="#{langList.languageName}" itemValue="#{langList}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

I get errors:

```
Conversion Error setting value 'reports.entety.LanguagesList@7ea21f4f' for 'null Converter'. Conversion Error setting value 'reports.entety.LanguagesList@7ea21f4f' for 'null Converter'.
```

and after googling faund advice and create converter:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "langListConverter")
public class LangListConverter implements Converter {
    private OracleDBReportOperatorsDao reportsDAO = new OracleDBReportOperatorsDao();

    @Override
    public LanguagesList getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String s) {
        return reportsDAO.getLanguages(s);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object o) {
        return ((LanguagesList) o).getLanguageName();
    }
}
```

But now i get another error:

```
j_idt21:j_idt46: Validation Error: Value is not validj_idt21:j_idt46: Validation Error: Value is not valid
```

It is my code:

```
languagesList = new LanguagesList();
public LanguagesList getLanguagesList() {
        return languagesList;
    }
languages = reportBll.getLanguages();
public List<LanguagesList> getLanguages() {
        return languages;
    }
```

Comment: what a wierd variable name languagesList is for variable tied to selectOOneMenu. For a second i thought you were going to save a collection in <h:selectOneMenu>. Why is your converter annotated with `@ManagedBean(name = "langListConverter") and not '@FacesConverter("langListConverter")?